# Apply hooks on inner layers of ResNet

Tags: pytorch, resnet

The [pytorch official implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L230) of resnet results in the following model:

```
ResNet(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (shortcut): Sequential()
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (shortcut): Sequential()
    )
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (shortcut): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (shortcut): Sequential()
    )
  )
 ### Skipping layers 3 and 4
  (linear): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

I tried applying hook to the conv1 in the first BasicBlock of layer2 using

```
handle = model.layer2[0][0].register_forward_hook(batchout_pre_hook)
```

but got the following error :

```
TypeError: 'BasicBlock' object does not support indexing
```

I am able to apply hook to the BasicBlock using  `handle = model.layer2[0].register_forward_hook(batchout_pre_hook)` but cannot apply hook in the modules present inside the BasicBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For attaching a hook to `conv1` in `layer2`'s 0th block, you need to use

```
handle = model.layer2[0].conv1.register_forward_hook(batchout_pre_hook)
```

This is because inside the 0th block, the modules are named as `conv1`, `bn1`, etc. and are not a list to be accessed via an index.

Comment: And given the the name of the desired layer, here "model.layer2[0].conv1", how do we apply the forward hook, without using the "exec" function and without manually specifying the name, but something like: name.register_forward_hook...  I tried it using getattr(model, layer_name), but since these lower-level layers are not attributes of the model, I can't access them in that way.